# How can I screen 8 glass diodes from light?

Tags: diodes, pcb-assembly

I have 8 no. DO-41 sized diodes in a row like so (representative image):-

[image: diode row]

I'm hoping to place them adjacent to each other on a 2.54mm pitched proto board.  They're glass cased and I need to totally screen them from all light.  They can't be screened via the overall circuit's enclosure as it's translucent.

It's a sign of good quality in that they actually manage to butt up against each other on a 2.54mm pitch, despite the data sheet suggesting they might not.  However this means that they cannot be heat shrink covered, due to lack of space.  So are there any alternatives to screening them from all light?  Remember that a proto board will have holes beneath the diodes.  The proto board is an Arduino shield of 80mm x 60mm size so I'm hoping to keep it tight.

For interest, this is the spec. for a DO-41 package:-

[image: DO-41 spec.]

Comment: hot glue. foil. more hot glue.

Comment: Grab a [faraday cover/"RF shield"](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/rf-if-and-rfid/rf-shields/867?k=shield&k=&pkeyword=shield&pv764=14&pv764=11&FV=1c0011%2C1c0002%2C1c0003%2Cffe00363&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=50)...nothing like a sheet of metal to block light.

Comment: Any reason you're not using diodes with opaque packages?

Comment: They said there's no room for heat shrink; the diodes are crammed in right next to each other.

Comment: How is it a sign of good quality that they butt up to each other? All that says is the tolerance stack gods were kind to you this time.

Comment: @AbeKarplus Is there such a beastie in a 2.54mm pitch?  RS Components don't have any that are not "representative" images.

Comment: @dandavis I only have one of the hot hot ones.  Is 210 deg.C okay?

Comment: Put heatshrink on the diodes, then install diodes 1, 3, 5, 7 flat against the board, followed by diodes 2,4, 6, 8 held off the board by the first four.

Comment: the glue is that hot or the dioides? black spray paint for wood-burning stoves can handle that heat. the cheap white heatsink compound is very opaque as well.

Comment: @dandavis  The glue.

Comment: @PeterBennett Excellent!  Teach me not to think 3 dimensionally.

Comment: Not worth making an answer out of it. What's wrong with 3M's black DP270? It is actually *intended* for use with glass diodes.

Comment: @jonk It's not available in the UK.

Comment: @PaulUszak Um. Hasn't 3M taken over the world, yet?? ;) Doesn't Digikey sell to the UK? What's wrong with the UK??

Comment: "I need to totally screen them from all light" - why?

Comment: @PaulUszak RS Components shows a variety of diodes in stock in many sizes in plastic packages, including DO-41. Do note that, as Matt Young says, you actually want a smaller package if you need 2.54mm pitch.

Comment: How many of these pcbs are you assembling?

Comment: @PaulUszak Btw: "*It's not available in the UK*" - [Sure it is](http://www.3m.co.uk/3M/en_GB/company-uk/3m-products/~/3M-Scotch-Weld-Epoxy-Potting-Compound-DP270?N=5002385+8709314+8710676+8710815+8711017+8711736+8713609+3293242430&rt=rud). It's even on [Amazon](http://amzn.eu/1bkjXQ8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A black, quick setting and thick/not runny epoxy could be poured over them.

Comment: Some inspiration: https://www.google.com/search?q=circuit+board+opaque+epoxy

Comment: Of course, potting compound is good for mass production, but a one off design or prototype can use standard epoxy from any hardware or auto store @jason

Comment: The only potting I've seen is of the whole circuit board.  Is that what you're suggesting?

Comment: @Paul no, you can pot individual components. That's what a Chip on Board is. I'm this case I'm saying just use some to cover the diodes.

Answer (score 2):

Paint them.   If these are already assembled, a suitable nonconductive
paint might be GC Electronics Corona Dope (10-4702), or Insulating Varnish(10-1762).   Be aware, though, that it may be important to block
infrared as well as visible light, so some testing should
confirm light blockage.

Answer (score 2):

Don't...

No idea why you would want them covered, but if your circuit is that sensitive to light, chose a different diode or package.

The cost difference in the devices will be far less than the costs involved, including labor, of covering them.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing that says that they have to be flush-mounted to the board.  Heat shrink them and stagger them vertically.